# HTML Entities in email from php mail()

Tags: php, email, html-entities

I'm having a strange problem trying to get an HTML email campaign to render the proper text I need.

I'm the legalese at the bottom of my email, there are instances where I need to add a trademark symbol. I've converted all those instances to `&#153;`, `$#0153;` or `&#8482;`, and when I run the mail script locally, everything looks as it should, however when I run the script on the intended server, all those trademark instances show an empty box character instead.

I should note that elsewhere on the email, I'm using other HTML entities that render fine... `&ndash;`, `&rsquo;`, `&ldquo;`  - No problems, only this damn ™ thats driving me crazy.

The offending code:
....`DisplayPort&#153; connectors, and/or DisplayPort&#153; compliant`....

renders as
[image]

Comment: Do you have semi-colons (&#153;) after your entities? Maybe post some code so we can see.

Comment: My bad, I do have semi-colons after the entities, dont know how I forgot entering them above.  I should also mention that changing the character encoding in the mail header didn't fix the issue as well.. happens when set to utf-8 and ISO-8859-1

Comment: Where is the trademark symbol displayed incorrectly? To be sure: your script sends the html-email. When you send it from your local server, the mail is displayed correctly in your email program, when you send it from your intended server, it is not displayed correctly in your mail program? Didn't get the context of sending and displaying emails :-)

Comment: Thank you for your edit... where do you display the email? At the same point? I think it is an displaying issue, not a sending issue, for example at one machine the default font has the tm symbol, at the other machine the default font has it not

Comment: I'm checking the emails in multiple web-clients at the moment.  I can send the exact same email from my localhost to a gmail account and the entites all work fine, but when I upload the same script to my remote server, all the entites except the trademark render, this is while viewing on gmail.com in any browser on any OS.

  Just to clarify, Im reading all the emails on the same machine, so local fonts shouldnt be an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved!

Apparently you can also use the entity code `&trade;` for a trademark, which I was unaware of.  It still doesnt explain why any of the other entity codes didn't work, but it has provided me with a working solution, so I'm calling this question answered.

Thanks to all for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check what character sets your "home" server and the "intended" server are using. If they're mismatched (like utf-8 at home, but latin-1 at work), that'd trash any of the non-standard ascii characters like the copyright symbol.

Comment: Just checked, the "intended" server is outputting the correct header information, I have two different emails, one sent in ISO-8859-1 and the other in utf-8, neither worked unfortunatly, but I can see the entity code in the raw text, and it looks correct.

What baffles me is that all the other entites work fine in the email, except this one.

Comment: Due to the fact that he uses html special chars, the encoding doesn't matter, does it? The specialchars are "translated" when they are displayed, so no encoding issues should be the reason